# three.js transparent objects in multiple scenes not working

Tags: three.js, transparent, renderer

I am using multiple scenes as a workaround for selective lighting. Now, I meet a difficulty in using transparent objects.

For simplity, I created a jsfiddle illustration:

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/curisiro/w9ke75ma/2/
```

I have two transparent squares which are in different scenes. The problem is I can see the blue square behind the red square (figure 1) but I can NOT see the red square behind the blue square (figure 2).

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

With material, by using other effects, depthTest and depthWrite must be set to true as default.

Do you have any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: If you insist on using two scenes, you can fix this problem by clearing the depth between the renders:

```
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  
  this.renderer.clear();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  renderer.clearDepth();            // <--- Like this
  renderer.render(scene1, camera);
}
```

However, this is limiting if you plan to add more complexity to the scene and need depth testing to take place between them. Alternatively, just render to the same scene:

```
let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
let material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0x0000ff, transparent: true, opacity: 0.4});
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

let geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
let material1 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xff0000, transparent: true, opacity: 0.4});
let mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
mesh1.position.z = 2;
scene.add(mesh1);
```

(see [forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90p86zLu/)). In this case, you would handle selective lighting some other way (layers, or custom materials perhaps, depending on what you need).

Comment: Hi Berthur,

Thank you for your reply.

As I mentioned, In my application, I have to use two scenes as a workaround for the selective lighting. And I faced this broblem.

Comment: @kiennt Oh I see, missed that. See my edited answer

Comment: Hi Berthur, thank you for your suggestion. I decided to use 1 scene and custom materials.